# How to typedef a function signature for a method in a template class where the parameter is a generic type

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, typedef

I've written a template class

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class ANotifier : public ACancelable
{
public:
  virtual std::weak_ptr<ACancelableToken> RegisterNotification( U msgType, std::function<void(T&)> fn ) = 0;
  virtual void Notify( U msgType, T& value ) = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class ASingleNotifier : public ANotifier<T, U>
{
...
}

template<typename T, typename U>
class AMultiNotifier : public ANotifier<T, U>
{
...
}
```

The base class provides a function signature in the lambda. I'm having to repeatedly define the function signature everytime I implement the function or want to make a stack variable of the specific function signature.

I was wondering if there is a way to create a typedef

So something like this

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class ANotifier : public ACancelable
{
public:
  typedef std::function<void(T&)>  NotificationFn
  virtual std::weak_ptr<ACancelableToken> RegisterNotification( U msgType, NotificationFn fn ) = 0;
  virtual void Notify( U msgType, T& value ) = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class ASingleNotifier : public ANotifier<T, U>
{
...
  virtual std::weak_ptr<ACancelableToke> RegisterNotification( U msgType, NotificationFn fn );
}

template<typename T, typename U>
class AMultiNotifier : public ANotifier<T, U>
{
...
  virtual std::weak_ptr<ACancelableToke> RegisterNotification( U msgType, NotificationFn fn );
}
```

Do I need to declare a typedef in each template subclass. Also when actually creating a stack variable to a function of a specific type how would I declare the fn. eg. `NotificationFn<uint32_t> fn;`

I used what I have above and I get this error:

> /Users/kartik/Projects/pancam/hardware/neolib/inc/ANotifier.h:36:76:
>   error: unknown type name 'NotificationFnOld'   virtual
>   std::weak_ptr RegisterNotification( U msgType,
>   NotificationFnOld fn )

where `NotificationFnOld` is the same as `NotificationFn`

What I want to do is be able to change the function signature in one place (ie add/rem params) and have it bound to the typedef. I don't mind declaring new typedefs in each subclass as long as I can just have one place to change the signature (ofcourse I will have to change the function implementations but I would like to avoid having to modify intermediate variables and stuff).

EDIT

I modified the typedef to a `using` and still got a similar error. This is what I used...
Instead of `typedef std::function<void(T&)>  NotificationFn;` 
I used `using NotificationFnOld = std::function<void( T& )>;`

And this is the error I got.

> /Users/kartik/Projects/pancam/hardware/neolib/inc/ANotifier.h:36:76:
>   error: unknown type name 'NotificationFnOld'   virtual
>   std::weak_ptr RegisterNotification( U msgType,
>   NotificationFnOld fn )

The error is reported on the Subclass `ASingleNotifier` in the prototype of overriden function `RegisterNotification`. It doesn't complain when the alias is used in the prototype declared in `ANotifier`. How do I cleanly use the alias in my subclasses ?

NOTE: `NotificationFnOld` and `NotificationFn` are used interchangeably in this question, I actually use only `NotificationFnOld` in my code.

EDIT

Incase details are needed, here is the code of what I'm trying.
There should be no relation with `ACancelable` but if more info is needed I will provide.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class ANotifier : public ACancelable
{
public:
  using NotificationFn = std::function<void( T&, std::weak_ptr<ACancelableToken> )>;
  using NotificationFnOld = std::function<void( T& )>;
  virtual std::weak_ptr<ACancelableToken> RegisterNotification( U msgType, std::function<void( T&, std::shared_ptr<ACancelableToken> )> fn ) = 0;
  virtual void Notify( U msgType, T& value ) = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class ASingleNotifier : public ANotifier<T, U>
{
public:
  virtual ~ASingleNotifier()
  { }

  virtual std::weak_ptr<ACancelableToken> RegisterNotification( U msgType, std::function<void( T&, std::shared_ptr<ACancelableToken> )> fn )
  {
    std::weak_ptr<ACancelableToken> retval;
    std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lk( m_mtx );
    std::shared_ptr <ATypedCancelableToken<U>> tmp( std::make_shared<ATypedCancelableToken<U>>( *this, msgType ));
    if( m_notifierMap.find( msgType ) == m_notifierMap.end() ) {
      m_notifierMap[ msgType ] = std::make_pair( fn, tmp );
      retval = tmp;
    }
    return retval;
  }

  virtual void CancelWith( std::shared_ptr<ACancelableToken> spBaseToken ) const
  {
    try {
      auto spToken = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<ATypedCancelableToken<U>>( spBaseToken );
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk( this->m_mtx );
      m_notifierMap.erase( spToken->m_msgType );
    }
    catch ( std::bad_cast exp ) { }
  }

  virtual void Notify( U msgType, T& value )
  {
    m_mtx.lock();
    auto it = m_notifierMap.find( msgType );
    if ( it != m_notifierMap.end() && it->second.first ) {
      auto fn = it->second.first;
      m_mtx.unlock();
      fn( value );
    }else {
      m_mtx.unlock();
    }
  }

protected:
  mutable std::map <U, std::pair<std::function<void( T&, std::shared_ptr<ACancelableToken> )>, std::shared_ptr<ATypedCancelableToken<U>>>> m_notifierMap;
  mutable std::mutex m_mtx;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class AMultiNotifier : public ANotifier<T,U>
{
protected:
  class AmnCancellableToken : public ATypedCancelableToken<U>
  {
  public:
    AmnCancellableToken( const ACancelable& cancellable,
                         U msgType,
                         typename std::list<std::pair<std::function<void( T&, std::shared_ptr<ACancelableToken> )>,std::shared_ptr<AmnCancellableToken>>>::iterator it ) :
        ATypedCancelableToken<U>{ cancellable, msgType }, m_it{ it } { }
    ~AmnCancellableToken() {}
    const typename std::list<std::pair<std::function<void( T&, std::shared_ptr<ACancelableToken> )>,std::shared_ptr<AmnCancellableToken>>>::iterator m_it;
  };

public:
  ~AMultiNotifier() { }
  virtual std::weak_ptr<ACancelableToken> RegisterNotification( U msgType, std::function<void( T&, std::shared_ptr<ACancelableToken> )> fn )
  {
    std::weak_ptr<ACancelableToken> retval;
    std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lk( m_mtx );
    std::shared_ptr<AmnCancellableToken> token;

    m_notifierMap[ msgType ].push_back( std::make_pair( fn, token) );
    auto it = m_notifierMap[msgType].end();
    token = std::make_shared<AmnCancellableToken>( *this, msgType, --it  );

    m_notifierMap[ msgType ].back().second = token;
    retval = token;
    return retval;
  }

  virtual void CancelWith( std::shared_ptr<ACancelableToken> spBaseToken ) const
  {
    try {
      auto spToken = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<AmnCancellableToken>( spBaseToken );
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk( this->m_mtx );
      if ( !m_notifierMap[ spToken->m_msgType ].empty()) { //If the list of handler is not empty
        m_notifierMap[ spToken->m_msgType ].erase( spToken->m_it ); //Delete the handler in list
        if ( m_notifierMap[ spToken->m_msgType ].empty()) //If the list is now empty
          m_notifierMap.erase( spToken->m_msgType ); // Delete the msgType Key element
      }
    } catch ( std::bad_cast exp ) { }
  }

  virtual void Notify( U msgType, T& value )
  {
    m_mtx.lock();
    auto anotherCopy = m_notifierMap;
    m_mtx.unlock();
    typename std::map<U, std::list<std::pair<std::function<void( T&, std::shared_ptr<ACancelableToken> )>, std::shared_ptr<AmnCancellableToken>>>>::iterator ait =
        anotherCopy.find( msgType );

    if( ait != anotherCopy.end() &&
        !ait->second.empty() ) {
      for( auto ait2 = ait->second.begin(); ait2 != ait->second.end(); ait2++ )
        if( ait2->first )
          ait2->first( value );
    }
  }

protected:
  mutable std::map <U, std::list<std::pair<std::function<void( T&, std::shared_ptr<ACancelableToken> )>,std::shared_ptr<AmnCancellableToken>>>> m_notifierMap;
  mutable std::mutex m_mtx;
};
```

Thanks for the help / suggestions

Kartik

Comment: I do not see any lambda in provided code.

Comment: Do you get errors when trying the typedef way?

Comment: The C++11 `using` syntax will read more clearly than the old `typedef` mechanism, consider using that instead.

Comment: Also, you need a semicolon after your typedef...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to qualify NotificationFn:

```
  virtual std::weak_ptr<ACancelableToken> RegisterNotification( U msgType, typename ANotifier<T,U>::NotificationFn fn );
```

Or if you are going to be using it multiple times, add a using statement:

```
using NotificationFn = typename ANotifier<T,U>::NotificationFn;
```

inside each derived class.

here's a complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

struct ACancelable {};
struct ACancelableToken {};

template<typename T, typename U>
class ANotifier : public ACancelable
{
public:
  using NotificationFn = std::function<void(T&)>;
  virtual std::weak_ptr<ACancelableToken> RegisterNotification( U msgType, NotificationFn fn ) = 0;
  virtual void Notify( U msgType, T& value ) = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class ASingleNotifier : public ANotifier<T, U>
{
  virtual std::weak_ptr<ACancelableToken> RegisterNotification( U msgType, typename ANotifier<T,U>::NotificationFn fn );
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/sXVkvw